# nested page-faulting of user-space address in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I  would like to know if it is functionally wrong to page-fault a  user-space address when kernel is running fault-handler to bring in a user-page.

OS is Linux 2.6.30

Assume that both user-addresses are valid  ( falling within vma , rw permission ) for the task.

When I check the kernel code,  i find that  the kernel does not mind the nested fault
if the faulted-addresses are valid and the fault did not occur in atomic-context or in irq handler.

(I dont think the answer is  cpu-specific,  but I would add that i am interested in
arm and mips ).

eg : The scenario can happen if I print stack-data from page-fault handler.

Comment: I was ready to answer this twice, checked myself, and I'm still not sure. +1 for a great question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through kernel sources for the last hour suggests that it is fine: Neither the definition of [struct vm_operations_struct](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.33/include/linux/mm.h#L184) nor the code between [handle_mm_fault()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.33/mm/memory.c#L3014) and the call to vma->vm_ops->fault in [__do_fault()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.33/mm/memory.c#L2724) has any cautionary statements about this, and the few ->fault handlers I looked at didn't seem worried about it either...

... I think the main thing is that you need to avoid going into an infinite recursion by faulting on the same address again, but that would presumably only happen if the kernel stack was in *your* vma, which is most likely not going to be happen?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely correct. As a matter of fact, you can even sleep.

*But* you can do it only once this [line](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1056) is passed, since you will be in non-atomic context.